Multiple users successfully authenticated, but SSH keys not working on Windows 11
I'm trying to set multiple GitHub accounts for multiple projects I'm working on. It just won't work.
First of all, I'm on Windows 11.

I've created the keys, they're in C:/Users/User/.ssh/...

I created a config file inside the same /.ssh folder and this is the content:
Host github-user1
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github-user1

Host github-user2
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile C:\Users\User\.ssh\github-user2

Notice I tried two ways of pointing to the key files. I also tried '/c/Users/User/.ssh/', which also does not work.

I added the public keys to both github accounts

I added the keys to the ssh agent

I edited the local repo git config file to use the correct remote origin and user, it looks like this:
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    sshCommand = ssh -i ~/.ssh/github-user1
[user]
    name = user1
    email = user1@domain.com
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github-user1:user1/repositoryName.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master


I tested authentication like so:
ssh -T github-user1

This worked, the user was successfully authenticated, for both users in both repositories

I checked the config with 'git config --list' and this was the output:
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
http.sslbackend=openssl
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
core.symlinks=false
pull.rebase=false
credential.helper=manager
credential.https://dev.azure.com.usehttppath=true
init.defaultbranch=master
core.sshcommand=C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
core.sshcommand=ssh -i ~/.ssh/github-user1
user.name=user1
user.email=user1@domain.com
remote.origin.url=git@github-user1:user1/repositoryName.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master

Looks correct to me...

Finally I test fetching 'git fetch' and this is what I get:
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github-user1: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

This happens with both users, that both authenticate correctly. No matter what I try, this is all I get.


Last thing I tried is 'ssh -vvv github-user1' to see whether it could connect, it did. But, this rule was in the output:
debug1: Will attempt key: wrongUser@domain.com RSA SHA256:blahblahblah agent

So appearantly it tries to connect with the wrong user. Also, if I prompt for this:
ssh -T git@github.com

The same wrong user comes up. So, where does this come from? I did not configure this anywhere. Before I started to configure ssh keys, I logged in and out of both accounts a few times, so I guess something got saved somewhere, but I haven't been able to find it anywhere. Anyone any idea where to look?
Also, I noticed that on github, it says the key as never been used:

I did delete the git user in the Windows References, so that is not the problem.

Your git config --list has in the output core.sshcommand=C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe. That what you should configure and use in tests: C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe -T github-user1. Tried simply unset it?

@phd I unset it and no difference.

You have 2 ssh and it seems you configured one in C:\Users\User\.ssh\config but Git uses the other and the other one doesn't use the same config. Try git -c core.sshCommand="ssh -vvv" fetch to see what SSH does, which config and key files it reads. Like this.

Ok, so here's my solution. As I already mentioned, when I tested ssh -T git@github.com I got the wrong user authenticated. I did not define git@github.com as a host anywhere. So I decided to set user1 as a default github.com host like so:
Host github.com
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github-user1

Host github-user2
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github-user2

The local repository git config file now looks like this:
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    sshCommand = ssh -i ~/.ssh/github-user1
[user]
    name = user1
    email = user1@domain.com
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:user1/repositoryName.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master

Also, I forgot to add the line sshCommand = ssh -i ~/.ssh/github-user2 in the local repository git config file for user2, so I added that as well. The config for user2 now looks like this:
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    sshCommand = ssh -i ~/.ssh/github-user2
[user]
    name = user2
    email = user2@domain.com
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github-user2:user2/repositoryName.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master

These steps fixed the problem for me. I can now fetch from git on both remote repositories and I can see in both github accounts that my keys are being used.

